# Javascript widget tracking with Google Analytics

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to figure out the best way to do tracking for a Javascript widget. I work for a non-profit and I have written a Javascript widget that websites can embed on their site. The piece of code they put on their site has a container for the widget (a div) and it loads our .js file. Our .js file populates the container with HTML to show an image and some info.

I'd like to be able to track the usage of this widget on other sites and the number of times it gets loaded (seen). We are using Google Analytics on our site so that seems like the most effective way to do it. I don't want to embed *our* GA code in the widget since that would more than likely screw up any GA tracking the other site may be doing.

My idea was to include a hidden iframe that loads a tracking page on our site and the tracking page would have the proper GA code in it. So, for example:
usersite.com embeds our widget on their page.
The .js file is served from mycompany.org/js/widget.js
the widget.js creates a hidden iframe on usersite.com (in our div) that loads mycompany.org/js/trackingpage.html (and maybe it includes a few parameters like domain=usersite.com or something that the js on the tracking page can pull off and log to GA) and trackingpage.html has our GA code to register that the widget has been used.

This seems like a simple way to solve this. Does this seem like a reasonable way to do this? or is there a better way?

Comment: You can alway do what Google does: create a (sub)domain  that serves nothing but a single pixel. On each event in your javascript widget request that pixel (with parameters for event name and any parameter that isn't sent with a http request anyways ). Write a script that parses the log file for that domain and hook the results up to an excel table or a commercial dashboard solution. Seems cleaner than messind around with GA. And talk to you clients so they can make sure they are allowed to deploy widgets that send parties to 3rd party servers (at least in Europe that's not longer a given).

Comment: Parsing logs sounds like a huge PITA. No thanks. But thanks for trying!

Comment: I have a very similar problem. Did you come up with a solution since you asked the question? Any tips?

Comment: @davidrac No, nothing yet. I haven't really tackled it yet. It's actually not high priority for anyone but me (since I wrote the widget) but I'd like to get something in place to track its usage.

Comment: Thanks. I've actually solved this for our widget. It's quite simple. I'll post the answer.

Answer (score 9):

Our widget works by the customer including a javascript file in his site. Our javascript code adds the widget to the needed places in the page.

Adding Google Analytics was quite simple: I added the GA code to the javascript file that is loaded by the customer site:

```
// setup google analytics
var _gaq = _gaq || [];
_gaq.push(['REPLACE_WITH_SOME_UNIQUE_NAMESPACE._setAccount', 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUE_GA_ID']);
_gaq.push(['REPLACE_WITH_SOME_UNIQUE_NAMESPACE._trackPageview']);

(function() {
  var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
  ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
  var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
})();
```

I also track other specific events directly from our Javascript like that:

```
  _gaq.push(['REPLACE_WITH_SOME_UNIQUE_NAMESPACE._trackEvent', 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_EVENT_CATEGORY', 'REPLACE_WITH_YOUR_EVENT_ACTION']);
```

**Important**

You **must** use the namespace in order to avoid colliding with the site's GA (if present)

You should configure your Google Analytics profile to also display the host. Google have a good explanation on that in [here](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSite#profilesKey) (under Modify your cross-domain profile with a filter to show the full domain in your content reports)

So far this approach seems to work fine as long as you make sure the cookie configuration (domain etc.) are similar to the hosting site's. If, for example, the host domain is different, it may cause duplicate hits.

Comment: what is this namespace? can I set any? do I need to configure it anywhere on google dashboard?

Comment: no. you just add it to the commands: e.g. REPLACE_WITH_SOME_UNIQUE_NAMESPACE._setAccount
BTW, since then I've moved to google universal analytics, which is less problematic in such cases.

Comment: Hey, I have a site that uses GA, and now I'm working on a widget that will be redistributed on other sites. They are the same app, but I want to separate GA for them. On GA Admin, should I create a new property or view? If I try to create a property, it's asking me for "Website URL", which I don't have, since it's not going to be used on my site. 

Please help.

Answer (score 0):

On the client site with the widget, have an ajax request that calls to your server to request the widget content. Tag the request URL with GA Campaign parameter information and you will be able to see widget traffic. The ajax response can be adjusted to fit the scenario.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you're saying tack on something like "?utm_campaign=widget" to the url when the widget requests resources? I'm not positive, but I don't think that will work. I think that will only work if the resource you're requesting has the GA JS code in it. Since what the widget requests is not HTML, it cannot have the GA JS in it, therefore it won't track it. I could be totally wrong about this though.